# I received the error message: Run-Time Check Failure #2. Stack around the variable was corrupted. However, I was not out of bounds of any array

Tags: c, visual-studio

I've been doing some exercise with structures to prepare for my upcoming exams, and I've run into a bit of trouble with this code.

```
// Creates a structure of type 'person' with a first name (nameF), last name (nameL), and the age (age)

typedef struct {
    char nameF[20];
    int age;
    char nameL[40];

}person;

// Main function
int main() {
    person ppl[2];  // We are creating 3 "people", whose information shall be printed into the file

        // This loop takes user input to create the names and ages of 3 people
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            printf("\nEnter first name %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("%s", &ppl[i].nameF);
            printf("%s\n", ppl[i].nameF);
        }
        printf("It worked\n");
        system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine, but when the program exits, I keep receiving an error message from the Debugger that states: "Run-Time Check Failure #2. Stack around the variable 'ppl' was corrupted."

So I looked it up on Stack Overflow, this error appears when you go outside the bounds of a string. I don't understand where in my code I'm going out of bounds.

Here's an example of the output:

```
Enter first name 1: 'Adolfo'
Adolfo

Enter first name 2: 'Cecilia'
Cecilia

Enter first name 3: 'Tim'
Tim
Press any key to continue...
```

And then the error message pops up.
As you can see none of my inputs exceed the maximum amount of characters for the variable 'nameF', so there should be no reason for me to receive the error.

I saw someone on Stack Overflow mention that instead of making a character array:

```
char nameF[20];
```

One should instead write use dynamic memory allocation:

```
char * nameF = malloc(<enough bites to support any input);
```

Unfortunately, I don;t quite have a grasp of memory allocation yet, and when I attempted this code, I received all sorts of other errors, and my program wouldn't even run.

What is the mistake?

Also, I am not sure if this information is important, but I wrote this code using Visual Studio in C.

Edit: "char * nameF[20]" to "char nameF[20]" that asterisk was a leftover from my previous attempts at fixing the code, sorry.

Comment: `char * nameF[20]`... sure about  `char*`?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)` - time to use your debugger!

Comment: "_We are creating 3 people", whose......_" actually your code shows pp1[2]. and your looping 3 times for pp1  of size 2.

Comment: `&ppl[i].nameF` is not what you want!

Comment: You don't allocate memory for the string pointers. All those errors show various missconceptions. Please recap the chapters about loops, arrays and pointer in the C book of your choice. Or get (a better) one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating two structures then filling it with three responses?

Also, scanf is very dangerous as it can easily be abused to overwrite past a buffer. Look for routines (or write one) that limits the input to the length of the string.

hint: scanf man page might lead you to a better version.

Comment: Allocating two structures and filling it in with 3 responses? Are you referring to the structure array 'ppl[2]'? I thought I was allocating 3 `ppl[0] ppl[1] ppl[2]`. Is this not right? Edit: Nevermind, I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Not meant as an answer, just made some adaptions allowing you to continue your work:

```
typedef struct {
    char nameF[20];  // may take on 19 characters (+ string terminating char)
    int age;
    char nameL[40];

}person;

int main() {
    person ppl[3];  // 3, not 2.
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            printf("\nEnter first name %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("%s", ppl[i].nameF);   // removed the &
            printf("%s\n", ppl[i].nameF);
        }
        printf("It worked\n");
        system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I use `ppl[3]`, wouldn't I be allocating 4 different structures instead of just the three I want? Edit: Nevermind, I got it.